How to design a snap lock for a PCB?
I drew a box for my electronic project. I'd like to place the PCB module (this one) into its holder, without using any screw. Currently I just made a slide:

but of course the PCB can freely exit from the front.
How to design a "lock" to keep the module in place?
I'll print this box with PLA.

What is your print orientation going to be?

@joojaa since the bottom of the box is flat, it will be printed as shown in the image

You are going to have problems with printing the slot because a FDM (?) printer  can not print on empty air. Or are are you using soluble supports? Anyway just make the slot tight at the entrance  no need to snap. I would worry much more about the overhang.

@joojaa it can be printed. I have one on my desk. Without supports.

Some observations about your design:

You need to continue those cutouts for the solder joints all the way to the end, or you wont be able to insert or remove the board once a header is soldered on.

It doesn't appear there are any parts on the bottom of the board, but the USB connector will still need clearance for the through hole solder joints.

A lot of clearance will be required inside your case to slide the board in and out.

A single screw or snap cleverly placed will be able to hold the board in.


Here's an example of a similar bracket I designed for the arduino nano. I've used it on multiple projects and it works. It uses snaps, and the board can be inserted from the top.

A few things to notice:

The snaps should be relatively small and also require only a small deflection. Otherwise the insertion force will be excessive.
There are cutouts around the snaps to give them a longer arm.
The board is constrained in all axis.
The board is being held from the corners to maximize access.


Great design! To have a rough idea, what are the dimensions at the base of the snaps? I guess something like 2x3 mm?

@Mark They're 2.5mm wide x 1.7mm thick. Arm length from ramp point to base plate is 3.85mm. Deflection is 0.5mm.

At the front design a tooth that will bend to allow the pub to slide in then "snap" over the end of the pub once it has passed the tooth.

I get it in theory, but how to determine the shape and the size? Is there any guideline you can provide? Otherwise I just need to do several trial&error iterations

Just look at all the "snap together black boxes" or white etc etc

Here's some numbers to get you started: snap deflection: 0.3mm, arm length 2.5mm, ramp angle 30deg, snap width 3mm. If you put a ramp on both sides the board can be pulled back out without manually depressing the snap.

With 3D printing it's easy to print small test pieces to check fitment. I recommend you experiment with that first.
